# Monitor Application Network Activity

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip, network-monitoring

I use TCPlogView to see all tcp activity of a software.
for example:

An app (`sample.exe`) downloads this file in background: `google.com/dl/sample.txt`

when I track it with a TCP software I see this:

```
local:192.168.1.2  hostname:google.com
```

But it doesn't show the full address. (`google.com/dl/sample.txt`) and it only shows me the host name. (`google.com`)

So is there any software to track FULL netwrok activity of an application with all details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the TCP level, the only addressing that you can see is the IP address and TCP port number of each end of the connection. TCPLogView is doing exactly what it is designed to do. Other protocols ride inside a TCP connection to provide services like web browsing (HTTP), file transfer (FTP), and mail transfer (SMTP). If you wish to capture what the various protocols that ride inside TCP datagrams are doing, you'll need a program that understands how to interpret that particular protocol.

There are also other transport layer protocols, like UDP, which can be used to send data over the network. If you want to know the full network activity of an application, you'll need to consider more than just TCP activity. Without knowing more about what you want to accomplish, it is hard to suggest an appropriate tool.

For HTTP, which I'm guessing is what you want based on the question, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) are pretty good. Wireshark is the more general of the two tools.

Answer (score 2):

[TcpLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/tcp_log_view.html) is the same as [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) and [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx); they only show you the current *state* of the network interface(s) on the system. That is, they only list the current connections’ endpoints, protocols, and status.

To see transient information like URLs and file content, you need to use a [packet sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_sniffer) for that. There are several to choose from, but many are too powerful and difficult to learn quickly. A good one to start with (and often, continue with) is [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html). It is very easy to configure and use, has capture and display filters, and provides all the information you want.

[image: Screenshoft of Nirsoft SmartSniff]